# TA (Abbreviation, AmE)

Tags: usage, american-english, colloquial-language, abbreviations

Context: in a book, two college girls are talking about their lives in a quite colloquial, friendly tone. One of them says: "I made out with my girl TA last week". Does anyone know what "TA" stands for here?

Thank you!

Comment: Teaching assistant. Usually a graduate student who proctors exams, sets up experiments, leads discussion groups, etc.

Comment: Given the college context, almost certainly [Teaching Assistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teaching_assistant). Try searching Google for 'College TA' to find pages like [this one](https://www.gradschoolhub.com/faqs/how-do-i-become-a-college-teaching-assistant-ta/#:~:text=A%20teaching%20assistant%2C%20also%20known,same%20tasks%20as%20professors%20do.&text=They%20teach%20classes%2C%20answer%20questions,classes%20than%20the%20professors%20do.)

Comment: Thank you both! "Teaching assistant" was my first thought given the context, but I just needed to dismiss the possibility of it being another jargon term.

Comment: Yale says "teachers must avoid sexual relationships with students over whom they have or might reasonably expect to have direct pedagogical or supervisory responsibilities, regardless of whether the relationship is consensual. Conversely, teachers must not directly supervise any student with whom they have a sexual relationship."

Comment: Thank you for the additional info! Also, I know this question might seem somewhat silly, but when she says "my girl TA"... Does she mean "my girl's TA" or "my girl, who is a TA"?

Comment: "My TA who is a girl."

Answer (score 2):

As Michael and Jeffery pointed out in the comments, in the context of a conversation between college students "TA" can be assumed to mean "teaching assistant," that is, an upperclassman or graduate student who is *assisting* the professor. This can range from simply grading students' work to conducting a regular study hour or lab (practical) session, or even delivering some lectures in place of the professor.

"My girl TA" means "my TA, who is a girl" (that is, "TA" is the noun and "girl" is an adjective which modifies it). The possessive does not mean that the TA *belongs* to the speaker but really the opposite—the TA has been *assigned to* the speaker. "Girl" as an adjective is not strictly correct usage; usually "girl" or "woman" are nouns and the adjective would be "female." But using "male" and especially "female" instead of "boy/man" and "girl/woman" can come across as clinical and stilted in everyday speech, so the usage is starting to shift.

It is not uncommon for a TA to be a woman and usually that information would not be germane to the conversation. But if a female student (who was not previously established as being homosexual) is talking about "making out" with her TA, it would usually be assumed that the TA is male, as heterosexuality is more common. That is why the author used "my **girl** TA."

Comment: Thank you for the extensive explanation! The hetero/homosexuality factor did not strike me here. However, being a native speaker of a gendered language, I needed to clarify that point in order to get a clear idea about whom they were talking. It's not the first time time I see "my [whatever]" used as a modifier, but in this case, the possibility of "TA" meaning something else (as stated above) confused me. Thank you again!

Comment: Girl is a noun adjunct, that is modifying the noun TA.